# How does R-policy affect bearish market?

Tags: macroeconomics, interest-rate

I would like to ask what will happen if the central bank decides to adopt R-policy for three different scenarios:

1. Loss of consumer confidence - i.e., consumer pessimism
2. Loss of investor confidence - i.e., investor pessimism (physical-capital investors; not financial instruments investors)
3. Bearish bond market - forecasting the bond market's downturn and people decide to decrease their bond-holding ratio accordingly

What will happen to case 1, 2, and 3 respectively if the central bank makes changes to interest rates, so that the LM curve is horizontal line and the corresponding AD curve is a vertical line?

I would highly appreciate if you could provide answers with details (possibly diagram?)

Comment: what kind of policy you assume central bank would take under those scenarios? Unless you specify what sort of interest rate setting rule the central bank should follow this is unanswerable

Comment: I assume that the central bank fixes the overnight interbank loan market interest rate at equilibrium interest rate (equilibrium in the sense that the interest rate is constant with the equilibrium of money supply and money demand)